# Call macros from a range/list

Tags: vba, excel

please your help with the following code:

1) Objective: Run the macros that are referred in a range.

2) Range("B1:B101") contains the list of macros to be run. For example, cell B1 contains the word Macro1 that refers to the macro with the same name, B2 refers to Macro2, and so on.

3) Macro1, Macro2... have been already created.

4) I've worked in the following code, but no luck yet:

```
Dim mCell As Range
Dim mRange As Range
Dim mMacro As String
mMacro = mCell.Value

Set mRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B101")

For Each mCell In mRange.Cells
    Application.Run Module2.mMacro
Next mCell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done some modification in your code, check if this is what you want:

```
Sub try()

Dim mCell As Range
Dim mRange As Range
Dim mMacro As String


Set mRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B101")

For Each mCell In mRange.Cells
    mMacro = mCell.Value
    Application.Run "Module2." & mMacro
Next mCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Application.Run` method takes a `String` as an argument, try to pass the name as a string:

```
Application.Run "Module2." & mCell.Value
```